# How do I click the cross button (the cancel button) on the sub form and go to the main form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know how to close a sub form and go to main form by clicking "close" button under file menu bar, but I don't know how to cancel a subform and go to main form by clicking the cross button --"cancel" which is located on the upper right corner.

[image]

and then back to the main form

[image]

Update:

I have tried go to form property, under Event,there is an item called, FormClosing, write a click event funcation name,i.e cancel_Click, and then press enter. Then I can write code under cancel_click, but it rises another problem. Since I want use same code here as the one under "close" on the menu (both can redirect back to the main form), when I close on menu bar, it appears two main form. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use Form.Closing event and then do what ever you want to do. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Set the FormClosing event for the sub-form to go to the main form. Set the FormClosing event for the main form to exit the program.

Comment: You should include some code to support you answer.